# Server is unwilling to process the request - Active Directory - Add User via C#

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

I used the example in [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#36) to add a user to an Active Directory group, but I get an exception with the message "Server is unwilling to process the request" when executing

`dirEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userDn);`

Comment: I would also like to add reference to link [C# : The server is unwilling to process the request](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.in/2012/03/c-server-is-unwilling-to-process.html). The link was helpful to me.

Comment: @Mauricio I would request you to answer your own question. Because this question is getting hits so that one can answer. But then he finds that it had been answered. So it will be good if you can answer it own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question took me a lot of time to solve. First of all, the error message looks like a joke. Second, there is nothing more, just that message.

Anyway, I managed to fix it by:

1. Making sure that `userDn` contains the whole path (e.g., `"LDAP://server-address/CN=" + userDn + ",OU=optional,DC=your-domain,DC=com"`. This is actually **very important**, if you don't supply the full path it will throw an **Exception from HRESULT: 0x80005000**.
2. Replacing `dirEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userDn);` by `entry.Invoke("Add", new object[] { userDn });`

Then I wanted to remove a user and I expected `entry.Invoke("Remove", new object[] { userDn });` to work. However, this devilish AD will only work if you use **lower case "remove"**, so `entry.Invoke("remove", new object[] { userDn });` worked for me.

Comment: You probably had the wrong type of searcher. There is no requirement to use the full LDAP path unless you are not working with the LDAP classes rather than the higher level DirectorySearcher and DirectoryEntry. This exception is always thrown when the format of the value is not acceptable. I agree the message is silly and should be changed to a validation exception with clear indication which validation check failed.

Comment: Maybe you found a workaround indirectly, but I think your issue was caused more by the type of searcher/root entry (e.g. sometimes you need to create the searcher which produces your entry from a global catalog, sometimes a DC, sometimes a domain).

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue where I was trying to add a member to a group. Specifically trying to add a group to a group and getting the same helpful error 'The server is unwilling to process the request' The answer provided by the OP did not work for me.

For me, the reason I was unable to add a group to my group was because the group I was trying to add members to was a 'global' scoped group whereas it needed to be a 'universal' scoped group. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yes this error is always thrown when the type of data requested in the update is rejected. In your case the type of group, in my case another error with the DN value.

Answer (score 2):

I got this generic error message when my path did not match the forest domain name.  For example, if my forest domain name is `ad.example.com`, and I am trying to create a group with path `CN=Users,DC=example,DC=net` one has .com the other has .net - they don't line up.  I would need to correct my group to match.  My group path should then be `CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com`.

Comment: This resolved my issue when I was trying to use Ansible to create an Active Directory user.  I needed to correct the Distinguished Name of the OU that I was trying to create a user in.  In Ansible terms, I needed to correct the community.windows.win_domain_user > path.

Answer (score 1):

[ldapwiki.com](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/WILL_NOT_PERFORM) describes potential causes for "The server is unwilling to process the request". Check *ExtendedErrorMessage* property of your exception to figure out what applies. In my case "00002145: SvcErr: DSID-031A1254, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM)". The following line resolved the issue:

```
ent.Properties["groupType"].Value = 8;
```

I had missed to set *groupType* and so attempted to nest a universal group in a global group. Find more information on groupType attribute in [ldapwiki.com](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/GroupType)

Comment: Applies too with `countryCode` property

Answer (score 0):

Just look out, because the start of the `.properties("distinguished Name")` can be different than the `.properties("cn")`. If the user is created with a `,` or `;` in the `.properties("cn")`, the start of the `.properties("distinguished Name")` will be the username with `\,` or `\;`.

This can give an error if u are trying to add a user you found by use of `.properties("cn")` to a Group.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was caused by an automated process trying to set the proxyAddresses attribute to a String with a non-ASCII character.  Appropriately so, AD wasn't happy.  This won't be the case for everyone, but perhaps it will help someone.

It's too bad that Microsoft can't provide a more specific error message for these cases.  It would save a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score -1):

After many days searching i find the problem. when you add user in group you must set "distinguished Name" not LDAP path.

You must write like this:

```
ent.Properties["member"].Add("CN=YourUserName,OU=optional,DC=yourdomain,DC=com");
```

This is wrong code:

```
ent.Properties["member"].Add("LDAP://CN=YourUserName,OU=optional,DC=yourdomain,DC=com");
```

Also when you do remove mast to save this rule

```
ent.Properties["member"].Remove("CN=YourUserName,OU=optional,DC=yourdomain,DC=com");
```

P.S. **ent** is **DirectoryEntry** object of group