# rename AD organizational unit

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to rename my AD organizational unit in c#.

I'm using the Rename command but a exception is thrown:

> The server is unwilling to process the request

The extended error message says:

> 00002077: SvcErr: DSID-031B0E76, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

I don't have issue changing other properties such as description.

Am I using the wrong command?

This is my code is currently:

```
using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(container))
{
    searcher.Filter = $"(OU={name})";
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;;

    var result = searcher.FindOne();

    using (var ou = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
    {         
        ou.Rename(newName);                                                                                            
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748970/server-is-unwilling-to-process-the-request-active-directory-add-user-via-c-s)? Anyway, please share the code you have trouble with.

Comment: What's the name of the OU you are trying to rename?  Are you sure it's an OU and not a container?

Comment: Yes it is the OU as far as I know, as I was able to change other properties such as 'description'. The OU name is 'Test Organization' and I was hoping to change it to 'Test Organization 2' or something simple to start with

Answer (score 0):

Really hairpulling but turns out I have to add "OU=" to the front of the rename.

so instead of :

```
   ou.Rename("newName");
```

I just had to write:

```
   ou.Rename("ou=newName");
```